# Select from last matching select menu in Capybara 1.1.2

Tags: capybara, hobo

I'm working with a Hobo app using the `input_many` tag to handle a many-to-many relationship on a form. This puts + and - buttons on the page, and the + adds a new `select` tag for picking the model on the other side of the relationship. This means that there can be an arbitrary number of `select` menus with very similar characteristics, distinguished only by an array index, like this:

```html
<select class="input belongs_to data_set_graph" name="graph_pane[data_set_graphs][0][data_set_id]">
[...options...]
</select>
<select class="input belongs_to data_set_graph" name="graph_pane[data_set_graphs][1][data_set_id]">
[...options...]
</select>
```

N.B. the join of GraphPanes and DataSets is polymorphic (there are many kinds of GraphPanes) so the actual CSS class name varies according to the kind of pane - it could be `data_set_a_graph_pane_data_set` or `data_set_b_graph_pane_data_set`.

We've been using Capybara 1.1.2 to test this. As long as we're only associating one DataSet with a GraphPane, we've been able to select them with a step definition like this:

```ruby
included_defs.each do |data_set_name|
  click_button "+"
  select_node = find(:css, '.input-many-item select') # There may be more than one of these?
  select_node.find(:xpath, XPath::HTML.option(data_set_name), :message => "cannot select option with text '#{data_set_name}'").select_option
end
```

However, now we need to associate two DataSets with a GraphPane, and the `find(:css, '.input-many-item select')` fails because there are two matching nodes.

It seems to me that if I could just always pick the last one, this would work, but I can't figure out how to do this with Capybara's selectors. (I think part of the problem is that it's not clear to me, in most of the examples I find, whether they refer to the 1.x DSL or the 2.x series.)

Ideas for sorting this out elegantly are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turns out to be using the "all" finder in Capybara:

```ruby
included_defs.each do |data_set_name|
  click_button "+"
  select_node = all(:css, '.input-many-item select').last # There may be more than one of these
  select_node.find(:xpath, XPath::HTML.option(data_set_name), :message => "cannot select option with text '#{data_set_name}'").select_option
end
```

`all` is like `find`, but it returns an array of matching nodes, so I can use `.last` and always get the last one.

Comment: Another option is using Xpath and the Xpath `last()` option: `find(:xpath, "(//div[@class='input-many-item'])[last()]/select")`.

Comment: Thanks @pjmorse -- This worked for me, attempting to choose the last option child of a select tag: `find(:xpath, "(//select[@id='deal_assigned_to_id'])/option[last()]").select_option`